# Apache Tiles or SiteMesh should I use?

Tags: apache, sitemesh, tiles-3

I have no experience in using both Apache Tiles and SiteMesh, and now I need to choose one, so which one I should choose? Any body have in experience in using them, could give me some suggestions?